# How to properly sanitize URL as a link in PHP?

Tags: php, url, escaping

I have a site where users can share a link to their homepage such as `http://example.com/user`. Currently, I am using the PHP function `filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` to validate the URL before adding it to database using prepared statement.

However, I realize that the PHP filter function accepts input such as `http://example.com/<script>alert('XSS');</script>` which could be used for cross-site scripting. To counter that, I use `htmlspecialchars` on the URL within the `<a>` tag and `rawurlencode` on the `href` attribute of the tag.

But `rawurlencode` causes the `/` in the URL to be converted to `%2f`, which makes the URL unrecognizable. I am thinking of doing a `preg_replace` for all `%2f` back to `/`. Is this the way to sanitize the URL for display as a link?

Comment: have you considered strip_tags() ?

Answer (score 3):

This is outdated now :

> I am using the PHP function filter_var($_POST['url'],
>   FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) to validate the URL before adding it to database
>   using prepared statement.

Instead of **FILTER_VALIDATE_URL**

you can use the following trick :

```
$url = "your URL"
$validation = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
if((bool)preg_match($validation, $url) === false)
    echo 'Not a valid URL';
```

I think it may works for you. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

After sanitizing, the URL Use, `XSS` related scripts, just change `%2f` character using

`str_replace('%2f', '/', $result)` after your your code, but before the `filter_var()` and it will change it back to its original character. So, your script can go on.

Comment: this is only a part of the problem. urlencode will spoil other characters as well. so, whole approach with urlencode is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow urls with tags.

A user inserting a tag to a url means its probably malicious.
Having "homepages" containing tags is just wrong.